# getting a block of public IP subnet from microsoft

Tags: azure

Does anyone know if its possible to have my corporate azure account to be assigned a block (e.g. subnet) of azure public IP within a region to make it easier to create firewall rules for my corporate firewall which blocks most outgoing ports.

Our customer does not want anyone sourced inside from the corporate .com account to have access to all 22 and 3389 ports out on the internet, but will limit them to a subnet if we can be assigned a subnet on which we will hang our bastion servers on.

Comment: Consult with Microsoft about it...?!

Comment: Yep.  Did so.  They will not provide this feature until later this year (4qtr 2016)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know about blocks of IP's, but you can certainly create a virtual network in which you create all your resources in Azure, and hten configure a firewall in azure, which will have a permanent IP. This can then be used to set up a site-to-site VPN thing between your corporate network and the machines in Azure. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/virtual-network/

For public facing ports, you can add another virtual network card and rest assured that the traffic on one card cannot, in any way pass over to the other, network connected card.

This would also be a better strategy than to set up a range of VM's in Azure with public IP's.